# Javascript causes div to get stuck alternating two classes

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a function that moves boxes around by setting classnames with JS. The issue is that somehow, the correct classes are set, at the right times, but the div alternates between the original class and the new one...every second. I will try to post the fiddle link here. There are four boxes on the page, clicking one successfully translates the other three to the left, and then expands the selected. This part works fine. The issue is when I click a left box with one of the four expanded. The expanded one begins the transition to the new class, but then starts going back to the expanded position... and then back and forth forever. I have tried clearing all classes from the div and then translating. I believe there is a design rule for JS I'm missing? Nothing I've tried changes the class battle.

**HTML:**

```
<section id="content">
    <div id="firstBox" class="firstBox" onclick="firstBoxController()">
        2000-2005
    </div>
    <div id="secondBox" class="secondBox" onclick="secondBoxController()">
        2005-2010
    </div>
    <div id="thirdBox" class="thirdBox" onclick="thirdBoxController()">
        2010-2015
    </div>
    <div id="fourthBox" class="fourthBox" onclick="fourthBoxController()">
        2015-2020
    </div>
    <div id="firstSub"  class="hidden"></div>
    <div id="secondSub" class="hidden"></div>
    <div id="thirdSub"  class="hidden"></div>
    <div id="fourthSub" class="hidden"></div>
</section>
```

**js:**

```
//var declarations
var first     = document.getElementById("firstBox");
var firstSub  = document.getElementById("firstSub");
var second    = document.getElementById("secondBox");
var secondSub = document.getElementById("secondSub");
var third     = document.getElementById("thirdBox");
var thirdSub  = document.getElementById("thirdSub");
var fourth    = document.getElementById("fourthBox");
var fourthSub = document.getElementById("fourthSub");

//movement functions
function firstLeft() {
    first.className = "firstLeft";
}

function firstExpand() {
    first.className = "expand";
    firstSub.className = "translateRight";
}

function secondLeft() {
    second.className = "secondLeft";
}

function secondExpand() {
    second.className = "expand";
    secondSub.className = "translateRight";
}


function thirdLeft() {
    third.className = "thirdLeft";
}

function thirdExpand() {
    third.className = "expand";
    thirdSub.className = "translateRight";
}


function fourthLeft() {
    fourth.className = "fourthLeft";
}

function fourthExpand() {
    fourth.className = "expand";
    fourthSub.className = "translateRight";
}

//controller functions

function firstBoxController() {

    if (first.classList.contains("firstBox")) {
        secondLeft();
        thirdLeft();
        fourthLeft();
    }

    if (second.classList.contains("expand")) {
        second.className = "";
        second.className = "secondCenter";
        secondSub.className = "hidden";
        window.setInterval(secondLeft, 1000);
    }

    if (third.classList.contains("expand")) {
        third.className = "";
        third.className = "thirdCenter";
        thirdSub.className = "hidden";
    }

    if (fourth.classList.contains("expand")) {
        fourth.className = "";
        fourth.className = "fourthCenter";
        fourthSub.className = "hidden";
        window.setInterval(fourthLeft, 1000);
    }

    window.setInterval(firstExpand, 1000);
}

function secondBoxController() {

    if (first.classList.contains("expand")) {
        first.className = "";
        first.className = "firstCenter";
        firstSub.className = "hidden";
        window.setInterval(firstLeft, 1000);
    }

    if (second.classList.contains("secondBox")) {
        firstLeft();
        thirdLeft();
        fourthLeft();
    }

    if (third.classList.contains("expand")) {
        third.className = "";
        third.className = "thirdCenter";
        thirdSub.className = "hidden";
        window.setInterval(thirdLeft, 1000);
    }

    if (fourth.classList.contains("expand")) {
        fourth.className = "";
        fourth.className = "fourthCenter";
        fourthSub.className = "hidden";
        window.setInterval(fourthLeft, 1000);
    }

    window.setInterval(secondExpand, 1000);
}

function thirdBoxController() {

    if (first.classList.contains("expand")) {
        first.className = "";
        first.className = "firstCenter";
        firstSub.className = "hidden";
        window.setInterval(firstLeft, 1000);
    }

    if (second.classList.contains("expand")) {
        second.className = "";
        second.className = "secondCenter";
        secondSub.className = "hidden";
        window.setInterval(secondLeft, 1000);
    }

    if (third.classList.contains("thirdBox")) {
        firstLeft();
        secondLeft();
        fourthLeft();
    }

    if (fourth.classList.contains("expand")) {
        fourth.className = "";
        fourth.className = "fourthCenter";
        fourthSub.className = "hidden";
        window.setInterval(fourthLeft, 1000);
    }

    window.setInterval(thirdExpand, 1000);
}

function fourthBoxController() {

    if (first.classList.contains("expand")) {
        first.className = "";
        first.className = "firstCenter";
        firstSub.className = "hidden";
        window.setInterval(firstLeft, 1000);
    }

    if (second.classList.contains("expand")) {
        second.className = "";
        second.className = "secondCenter";
        secondSub.className = "hidden";
        window.setInterval(secondLeft, 1000);
    }

    if (third.classList.contains("expand")) {
        third.className = "";
        third.className = "thirdCenter";
        thirdSub.className = "hidden";
        window.setInterval(thirdLeft, 1000);
    }

    if (fourth.classList.contains("fourthBox")) {
        firstLeft();
        secondLeft();
        thirdLeft();
    }

    window.setInterval(fourthExpand, 1000);
}
```

**css:**

```
.firstBox, .secondBox, 
.thirdBox, .fourthBox {

    width:70%;
    left:12.5%;

}

.firstBox, .secondBox, .thirdBox, 
.fourthBox, .firstSub, .secondSub, 
.thirdSub, .fourthSub, .translateRight, 
.firstLeft, .secondLeft,
.thirdLeft, .expand,
.fourthLeft, .hidden, 
.firstCenter, .secondCenter,
.thirdCenter, .fourthCenter {

border-style: solid;
border-color: black;
position:absolute;
color:white;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
cursor:pointer;
-webkit-transition: 1s linear;
-moz-transition: 1s linear;
-ms-transition: 1s linear;
-o-transition: 1s linear;
transition: 1s linear;

}

.hidden {

visibility:hidden;
opacity:0;

}

.firstBox, .firstLeft, .firstCenter {

top:1.125%;
bottom:75.125%;

}

.secondBox, .secondLeft, .secondCenter {

top:26.25%;
bottom:50.5625%;

}

.thirdBox, .thirdLeft, .thirdCenter {

top:50.5625%;
bottom:26.25%;

}

.fourthBox, .fourthLeft, .fourthCenter {

top:75.125%;
bottom:1.125%;

}

.expand {

width:70%;
top:1.25%;
bottom:1.25%;
left:12.5%;

}

.firstLeft, .secondLeft, 
.thirdLeft, .fourthLeft {

left:.5%; 
width:11.5%;

}

.firstCenter, .secondCenter, 
.thirdCenter, .fourthCenter {

width:50% !important;
left:25% !important;


}

.translateRight {

width:15%;
left:83%;
top:1.25%;
bottom:1.25%;

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sirjackk1888/suz5tuvk/#&togetherjs=lfb64hCRVu

Comment: double spacing is actually harder on the eyes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the desired functionality by changing `setInterval` method to `setTimeout` as can be seen in this demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/suz5tuvk/1/). This will execute your functions only once instead of repeatedly calling them again every second.

But surely you can improve your code a lot more than that.

**UPDATE**

I think you could shorten your code to as below. Check demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/z2kqn7rL/)

```
function moveLeft() {
    this.el.className = "left";
}

function expand() {
    this.el.className = "expand";
    this.elSub.className = "translateRight";
}

var obj = {
    "first": {
        "el": document.getElementById("first"),
        "elSub": document.getElementById("firstSub")
    }
    , "second": {
        "el": document.getElementById("second"),
        "elSub": document.getElementById("secondSub")
    }
    , "third": {
        "el": document.getElementById("third"),
        "elSub": document.getElementById("thirdSub")
    }
    , "fourth": {
        "el": document.getElementById("fourth"),
        "elSub": document.getElementById("fourthSub")
    }
}


//movement functions
function boxController(el) {

    for (var key in obj) {
        if (el.id != key) {
            if (obj[key].el.className === "expand") {
                obj[key].el.className = "center";
                window.setTimeout(
                    function(o) { return function() { moveLeft.call(o) }; }(obj[key]),
                  1000
               );  
                obj[key].elSub.className = "hidden";
            } else {
                moveLeft.call(obj[key]);
            }
        }
    }

    window.setTimeout( function(o) { expand.call(obj[el.id]) }, 1000);     

}
```

And markup

```
<section id="content">

    <div id="first" class="box" onclick="boxController(this)">1 2000-2005</div>
    <div id="second" class="box" onclick="boxController(this)">2 2005-2010</div>
    <div id="third" class="box" onclick="boxController(this)">3 2010-2015</div>
    <div id="fourth" class="box" onclick="boxController(this)">4 2015-2020</div>

    <div id="firstSub" class="hidden">1</div>
    <div id="secondSub" class="hidden">2</div>
    <div id="thirdSub" class="hidden">3</div>
    <div id="fourthSub" class="hidden">4</div>

</section>
```

Comment: That was the issue. Thank you. Apart from indentation edits everyone was quick to point out, how else would you improve it? I am not far into JavaScript.

Comment: Hi! I updated answer with some ideas of how I would improve the code